# remove space between quotation and first letter

Tags: javascript, list

```
function FullName(id){
  var firstName = getColumn("Olympic Medals", "Athlete First Name");
  var lastName = getColumn("Olympic Medals", "Athlete Last Name");
  var ID = getColumn("Olympic Medals", "id");
  for(var i=0; i<firstName.length; i++){
    if(ID[i] == id){
      return firstName[i] + " "+ lastName[i];
    }
  }
  
  return "Not found";
}
```

This code combines the full name and last name of a person based on their id number.

```
console.log (FullName("1", true));
```

When I used console.log to check whether the full name is correctly written, I found that there is a space between the quotation mark and the first letter,
like this:
" Alexandre Despatie"
.Can anyone help me to remove the unwanted space?

Comment: [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) (the process in most languages of removing superfluous spaces is called "trimming")

Comment: Try `return (firstName[i] + " "+ lastName[i]).trim();` in your return statement

Comment: thanks guys! It worked in removing the space now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `.trim()`

```
function FullName(id){
  var firstName = getColumn("Olympic Medals", "Athlete First Name");
  var lastName = getColumn("Olympic Medals", "Athlete Last Name");
  var ID = getColumn("Olympic Medals", "id");
  for(var i=0; i<firstName.length; i++){
    if(ID[i] == id){
      return (firstName[i] + " "+ lastName[i]).trim();
    }
  }
  
  return "Not found";
}
```